# Regex validation pattern only allows one character

Tags: php, regex, quantifiers

I'm trying to make functions for validating usernames, emails, and passwords and my regex isn't working. My regex for usernames is `^[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]$` and when I put anything through that should work it always returns false.

As I understand it, the `^` and `$` at the beginning and the end means that it makes sure the entire string matches this regular expression, the `a-z` and `A-Z` allows all letters, `0-9` allows all numbers, and the last three characters (the space, underscore, and dash) allow the respective characters.

Why is my regular expression not evaluating properly?

Comment: do you really expect e-mail address being 1 character long? Have you tried something like `^[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+$` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a quantifier, `+` or `*`. As it was written that only allows 1 of the characters in the character class.

Your `a-zA-Z0-9_` also can be replaced with `\w`. Try:

```
^[\w -]+$
```

`+` requires 1 or more matches. `*` requires 0 or more matches so if an empty string is valid use `*`.

Additionally you could use `\h` in place of the space character if tabs are allowed. That is the metacharacter for a horizontal space. I find it easier to read than the literal space.

**Per comment, Update:**

Since it looks like you want the string to be between a certain number of characters we can get more specific with the regex. A range can be created with `{x,y}` which will replace the quantifier.

```
^[\w -]{3,30}$
```

Additionally in PHP you must provide delimiters at the start and end of the regex.

```
preg_match("/^[\w -]{3,30}$/", $username);
```

Additionally, you should enable error reporting so you get these useful errors in the future. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/3783243

Comment: That still doesn't work. This is my code:

```
function valid_username(string $username)
{
    $username_length = strlen($username);
    return ($username_length >= 3 && $username_length <= 30 && preg_match("^[\w -]+$", $username));
}
```

Comment: string(4) "Test"

Answer (score 2):

You're not specifying the character count. Lets try this instead:

```
^[A-z0-9]*$
```

Where `[A-z0-9]` states that you can use any alphanumeric characters and that it *is* case sensitive.

The `*` specifies how many characters, and in this case is unlimited. If you wanted to max out your username length to 10 characters, then you could change it to:

```
^[A-z0-9]{10}$
```

Whereby the `{10}` is specifying a maximum of 10 characters.

**UPDATE**

To also allow the use of underscores, hyphens and blank spaces (anywhere in the string) - use the below:

```
^[A-z0-9 _-]{10}$
```